# How to fix warning in extending a generic method in java?

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

There's a interface in third lib, which can not be modified. And I need to extend it. Code is like below:

```
// 3rd interface
interface Client {
    void create(String path);
    void delete(String path);
    List<String> getChildren(String path);
    <T> T getChildListener(String path);
    xxxx
}

// 3rd abstract
AbstractClient<T> implements Client {
   xxx
   T getChildListener(String path) {
       return xxx;
   }
   xxx
}
```

My code like below:

```
class MyClient extends AbstractClient<PathWatcher> {
    ...
}
```

Compiler warnings that:

> return type requires unchecked conversion from xxx to T

I try to add `@SuppressWarnings(xxx)` with cast, warning, all.
It does not work. How can I fix this warning?
I **can not** modify the third lib.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. What are all those `xxx` about?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you exactly want. But what do you really want from

```java
interface Client {
    void create(String path);
    void delete(String path);
    List<String> getChildren(String path);
    <T> T getChildListener(String path);
}
```

It seems a bit weird to specify in this way, as I don't think the interface by itself knows what T really is.

A better interface setup may be the following:

```java
interface Client<T> {
    void create(String path);
    void delete(String path);
    List<String> getChildren(String path);
    T getChildListener(String path);
}

public class AbstractClient<T> implements Client<T> {
   T getChildListener(String path) {
       return xxx;
   }
}

public class MyClient extends AbstractClient<PathWatcher> {
    ...
}
```

Not sure, if this is what you want, though.

Comment: P.S. To learn more about Generics, you can have a look at 廖雪峰網頁https://www.liaoxuefeng.com/wiki/1252599548343744/1265102638843296. For complete understanding, go to have a look at Java Generics, by Oreilly. 
https://www.amazon.com/_/dp/0596527756?tag=oreilly20-20

Comment: Thank you. The design of third lib is a bad idea. But I can not modify the interface.

Comment: In case if you don't mind you can share the library code, so that the community and I can help u.

Comment: dubbo-remoting-etcd3 [EtcdClient](https://github.com/apache/dubbo/blob/2.7-native_image/dubbo-remoting/dubbo-remoting-etcd3/src/main/java/org/apache/dubbo/remoting/etcd/EtcdClient.java)  I need to extend etcd client with ssl support.

Answer (score 0):

A compromise : add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` on MyClient class.